# Elasticsearch fails with NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am running elasticsearch image like this:
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:5.4
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
```

I can check it is running with curl.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health
```

Response:

```
{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":0,"active_shards":0,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}
```

In application I configure TransportClient like this:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public TransportClient transportClient() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                        InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    }
```

And then I want to check it:

```
@Autowired
private TransportClient client;
@GetMapping(value = "test")
    public Object test(){
        return client.admin().cluster().health(Requests
                .clusterHealthRequest())
                .actionGet();
    }
```

but it fails with exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{_atMOwK5R5mgOXqAPJWvWg}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

BTW I am using this dependency: `compile('org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.4.0')`

Comment: Have the same situation/error (grails client, docker-compose + es 5.3 ). Did you solve it in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of local host try to give elasticsearch since this is your container name, in case spring boot app also running in docker

Comment: spring boot is outside the docker. InetAddress.getByName("elasticsearch"), 9300) leads to UnknownHostException: elasticsearch: Name or service not known

Comment: from your browser could you able to get the response for http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health

Comment: Yes. It is same as form curl